# Creating Zip file and emailing it in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using Cucumber Framework to automate my application. Now I am executing my application via jenkins. My automation script creates extended cucumber report in folder. How can I zip report folder and email it?

Comment: FYI: Are you sending to your own mail server, or to outside addresses? Because some mail hosts (GMail for instance) have started blocking things like executables, even when found within zip files. If you've got users on such a host, you might run into trouble through no fault of your own.

Comment: Apart from what @MichaelKohne is mentioning, depending on the OS that Jenkins is running on, you could add a post-build `Execute shell` or `Execute Windows Batch command` step that calls the zip tool of your choice, and send an e-mail with attachments using the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the file via using a pipeline script as

```
stage('Zipping Report'){
    echo "ZIP"
    zip zipFile: 'Report.zip', dir: pwd()+"/results/"+folderName.trim()
    echo "END - ZIP"
}
```